# Extract Path from FullName property into results

Tags: powershell

I have this script:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path R:\MyFolder\archive -Recurse |
>>  Sort-Object -Property LastAccessTime |
>>  Select-object -Property Name, FullName
```

Rather than FullName I'd like the Path without the files name so I tried to adapt as follows:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path R:\MyFolder\archive -Recurse |
>>  Sort-Object -Property LastAccessTime |
>>  Select-object -Property Name, [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName(fullname)
```

I'm obviously very new to `PS` - is it clear what I am attempting, and failing, to do?

Comment: Instead of `FullName` you use `Directory`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet returns objects of different type:

- `System.IO.FileInfo`
- `System.IO.DirectoryInfo`

Unfortunately, on the latter you do not find property called `DirectoryName`. You can use `Get-ChildItem -File` (the `-File` parameter eliminates such objects), or use calculated property as follows:

```
$rootPath = 'R:\MyFolder\archive'
Get-ChildItem -Path $rootPath -Recurse |
    Sort-Object -Property LastAccessTime |
    Select-Object -Property Name,
        @{ Name       = 'DirectoryName';
           Expression = { $_.FullName | Split-Path }}
```

For explanation, read in [Select-Object => Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7#parameters):

> **-Property**
>
> Specifies the properties to select. These properties are added as
> NoteProperty members to the output objects. Wildcards are permitted.
>
> The value of the Property parameter can be a *new calculated
> property*. **To create a calculated property, use a hash table**.
>
> Valid keys are:
>
> - Name (or Label):
> - Expression  or

Answer (score 1):

How about :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'R:\MyFolder\archive' -Recurse | Sort-Object -Property LastAccessTime | Select-object -Property Name, DirectoryName
```

?